# Large replace in XML

Tags: text-processing, scripting, cat, xml

Okay, so I have this xml file. I need to replace every key value with a value from another file (txt). Both files are sorted so line 20 i.e inside the xml

```
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value="testvalue1"/>
```

Within my second file, on line 20 will be

```
testvalue2
```

I am looking for something which will change the value from testvalue1 to testvalue2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.
We load the new values file, and then we process then xml file by replacing old value with new value using line number as the key.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{$NF=gensub(/value=".*"\/>/,"value=\""a[FNR]"\"\/>","g",$NF);print}' file2 file
#OR working with regex groups:
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{$NF=gensub(/(value=")(.*)(".+)/,"\\1"a[FNR]"\\3","g",$NF);print}' file2 file
```

Testing:

```
$ cat file
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value="testvalue1"/>                                                                                                             
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value="testvalue2"/>                                                                                                             
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value="testvalue3"/>                                                                                                             
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value="testvalue4"/>
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value=""/>

$ cat file2
newvalue1
newvalue2
newvalue3
newvalue4                                                                                                                          
newvalue5

$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{$NF=gensub(/value=".*"\/>/,"value=\""a[FNR]"\"\/>","g",$NF);print}' file2 file
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value="newvalue1"/>
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value="newvalue2"/>
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value="newvalue3"/>
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value="newvalue4"/>
<word key="ACTIVE" group="Service application" value="newvalue5"/>
```

Comment: @JamesBerrisford Updated with a better regex to carch even empty values of initial xml file.

Answer (score 0):

A quick bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set IFS to new line
IFS=$'\n';
line_number=0
for line in $(cat file1.xml); do        
    ((line_number++))
#get the value you want to replace
    value1=$(echo $line | grep -o -P 'value.{0,1000}' |  cut -d '"' -f 2)
#get the value you are replacing it with
    value2=$(sed "${line_number}q;d" file2.txt)
#run the replace using sed
    sed -i 's/'"${value1}"'/'"${value2}"'/g' file1.xml
done
```

Note that this is untested, but it should work for your needs.